# Generating words in a finitely presented group in SAGE

Tags: gap, finitely-generated, sagemath, cayley-graphs

I'm trying to get a list of all words of length $n$ (in the word metric sense) in some finitely presented group. I have tried some very naive enumerations but it is very slow. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Do you care about different words, or different elements (I.e. a shortest word?) for what kind of group?

Comment: A discrete subgroup of SL2R generated by 2 elements with some relations between them. I'm interested in reduced words only (A^2A^-1 has length 1 for example).

Comment: In other words, take the Cayley graph with the obvious graph metric, and compute the ball of size n.

Comment: If you know matrix images of your generators, you could form words of increasing length systematically and discard if the evaluated images are equal. Otherwise, unless you happen to be able to have a confluent rewriting system, I doubt there is a better method.

Answer (score 1):

It might be too naive, but you can iterate on the elements of the free group, then use these elements to compute a representative in the group. It works decently well on the example I picked from GAP documentation, but it is certainly not perfect. If you give a more concrete example of a group you're looking at this can certainly be optimized.

```
m1 := [ [ Z(3)^0, Z(3)^0,   Z(3) ],
        [   Z(3), 0*Z(3),   Z(3) ],
        [ 0*Z(3),   Z(3), 0*Z(3) ] ];;
m2 := [ [   Z(3),   Z(3), Z(3)^0 ],
        [   Z(3), 0*Z(3),   Z(3) ],
        [ Z(3)^0, 0*Z(3),   Z(3) ] ];;
G := Group( m1, m2 );


hom:=EpimorphismFromFreeGroup(G:names:=["a", "b"]);;


PreImagesRepresentative( hom, m1*m2^(-1) );

iter := Iterator(G);
##test if we iterate directly on the matrix group, not very efficient


F2:=FreeGroup("a","b");

iterF2 := Iterator(F2);
##iterator on the free group, used to get the reduced words


toMatrixGp:=function(gen,w)
##computes the element in G via a->m1 and b->m2
    local temp;
    x:=gen[1]^0;
    for i in [1..NumberSyllables(w)] do

            temp:=(gen[GeneratorSyllable(w,i)]^(ExponentSyllable(w,i)));
        x:=x*temp;  


    od;

    return x;
end;



elmtSet:=Set([]);
##set of all different elements 
for i in [1..1000] do
    w:=UnderlyingElement(NextIterator(iterF2));
    g:=toMatrixGp(gen,w);
    elmt:=(PreImagesRepresentative( hom, g ));
    Print(elmt,"\n");
    AddSet(elmtSet,elmt);
od;
```